# Count attributes of agentset in monitor?

Tags: netlogo

I have a monitor and I want to calculate the sum of all "savings" in a particular agent set.

For example, I have a breed, men:

```
breed [men man]
turtles-own [ age savings ]
```

Pseudo-code attempt:

```
count [savings] of men
```

My monitor shows N/A, which is incorrect. I can confirm that `savings` exist by inspecting an individual `man` agent, which shows a positive value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
show sum [savings] of men
```

The reason it didn't work is because I was attempting to show an agentset as a number whereas I should have been counting the sum of the global attributes in that agentset.